# How to pass lazy variables to a functions parameters without them being evaluated unless returned

Tags: python, language-agnostic, lazy-evaluation

This question is aimed at python, although I don't mind users sharing experience from other languages.

Basically my problem is trying to pass lazy variables to a function. (in my case i may have no control over the function, so can't change it to take a generator as input).

Example (note that dict.get is an example of a function, but it could well be foo)

```
def calc():
    sleep(10**100)
    return 42

def my_args():
    yield 'meaning'
    yield calc()


#Instead of

meaning_of_life = dict_.get('meaning', calc())

#I would rather

meaning_of_life = dict_.get(my_args)
```

I don't suppose there are any one line elegant solutions? Possibly complicated monkey patching is required? (if so it's not worth it for me to try).

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have python clue but is not a generator just an instance of a class whose member function is an iterator?

Comment: Yes starbolin, so the next value would be 'meaning' and then the next value would be calc(). But if we pulled out after 'meaning', then we would never need to generate calc(), but functions assign parameters regardless, so calc() will unfortunately be called

Comment: Oh, but you want a symbol table name that looks like a static but is late bound to a function runtime. ??? You are passing to?...python, dll, ??

Comment: Only if pass-by-value not if pass-by-reference. Please clarify, you don't want calc to be called until when?

Comment: In the function it would have some if statements. One of those if statements is only entered sometimes (it depends on what the first couple function parameters look like). In that if statement is the only place calc needs to be called. Otherwise it shouldn't be called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a special object to defer computation until the object is first used.  It looks a [Lazy Proxy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/objproxies#lazy-proxies) will do what you want.

Comment: thanks that's what I was looking for - will have to look at the internals at some point.

Comment: @robertking Presumably it overrides the double-underscore methods that are used to implement Python's native functions and operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
meaning_of_life = dict_.get('meaning') or calc()
```

Comment: +1 that's really nice, but my actual function isn't a dict, so may not return None

Comment: The problem with this is that `dict_['meaning']` might be a Falsey value. It could even be `None`

Comment: Sure, okay then: `dict_['meaning'] if 'meaning' in dict_ else calc()` -- lots of ways to do this. I think the OP is overcomplicating things with generators et al.

Comment: @bluepnume i was using 'dict_.get' as an example function. I want a solution that would work for 'some_complicated_function'

Comment: OK, so what behavior does some_complicated_function exhibit when it doesn't return the value you want? Does it return a particular value? Does it raise an exception?

Comment: Ah, my mistake bluepnume, I put "unless being returned" in the question subject. Really what is returned is a function of what I put in, e.g. it could be 42*5 or something.

Comment: You're going to have to give some more clues. Can't you just tell us what the function is? Specifics are really useful when solving these kinds of problems.