# Why is the default value always computed?

Tags: python, dictionary, default

Let's say I have a dictionary `d` that has either a key 0 or a key 1. I want to assign to `x` the value `d[0]` if it exists and `d[1]` otherwise. I also want to destroy key 0 if it exists. I would write:

```
    x = d.pop(0,d[1])
```

But then running this for `d = {0:'a'}` raises an error.

Similarly, let's say I have a function that takes a keyword argument `x`. If `x` is computed already, then I want to use the value that is given. Otherwise, I need to compute it.

```
    import time
    def long_calculation():
        time.sleep(10)
        return 'waited'

    def func(**kwargs):
        x = kwargs.pop('x',long_calculation())
        return x
```

Running `f(x='test')` takes 10 seconds.

I could do something like

```
    x = kwargs.pop('x',None)
    if x is None:
        x = long_calculation()
```

But this is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: *"Why is it always computed?"* - Because it's a regular value passed into a regular function; you would expect `baz` to be evaluated in `foo(bar, baz)` before the function is called, right?

Comment: I don't understand. What value would you expect to get by doing `d[1]` when `1` does not appear in `d.keys()`...? If you want a default value, then  you need to specify it- like `x = pop(0,d.get(1,<default>))`

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747751/how-to-pass-lazy-variables-to-a-functions-parameters-without-them-being-evaluate ?

Comment: @deceze Absolutely! I just thought there could be some kind of lazy evaluation implemented in pop. Any idea how to circumvent it?

Comment: As for the second problem: you can just cache the calculation. Have a look at [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For caching function results, have a look at [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html). Example:

```
from functools import lru_cache
@lru_cache(maxsize=32)
def long_calculation():
    time.sleep(10)
    return 'waited'
```

The second call returns the cached value:

```
print(long_calculation()) # 10 seconds
print(long_calculation()) # instant
```

If you just want to short circuit `dict.pop()` I think it's more straightforward to just put it in nested `try` blocks. Like:

```
try: 
    d.pop(0)
except KeyError:
    try:
        d[1]
    except KeyError:
        <expensive value>
```